# visualforce page not reloading on force.com site

Tags: force.com

i have developed visualforce page to updating user profile information, this page appending on home page. once user submit the profile page it's reloading in salesforce but it's not through force.com site.

Could you please help on this.

Thanks,
Mouli

Comment: You should put in some more details such as your code to get relevant answers.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have used standard url '/apex/YourPageName' for redirecting if yes you need to append domain name of site so it would redirect properly. Or you can just write a piece of Javascript to reload the current window and it would work in both sandbox and site.
If that doesn't work, need to check your code.
Hope it helps you.